# how to see the result xml files after using xslt

Tags: xml, perl, xslt

i know it seems to be stupid, but how can i see the result xml? for example the original xml:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="root.xsl"?>
<root>   
<list>    
<a>aaaa</a>     
<b>bbbb</b>  
</list>
</root>
```

and the corresponding xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" > 
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="evalue">cccc</xsl:param>  
  <xsl:param name="ename">c</xsl:param>
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">    
    <xsl:copy>    
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />  
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  
  <xsl:template match="list">   
    <xsl:copy>     
      <xsl:apply-templates/>    
      <xsl:if test="not(c)">    
        <xsl:element name="{$ename}"><xsl:value-of select="$evalue"/></xsl:element>    
      </xsl:if>   
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and i want to see the result:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="root.xsl"?>
<root>   
<list>    
<a>aaaa</a>     
<b>bbbb</b> 
<c>cccc</c> 
</list>
</root>
```

not:

```
aaaabbbbcccc
```

i try the perl moudle:XML::XSLT

```
 use diagnostics;
 use XML::XSLT;
 my $xsl='root.xsl';
 my $xmlfile='root.xml';
 my $xslt = XML::XSLT->new ($xsl, warnings => 1);

 $xslt->transform ($xmlfile);
 print $xslt->toString;

 $xslt->dispose();
```

but it dosen't work, i have never used xslt before, am i on a wrong way?

thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be a question about the Perl XML/XSLT API, rather than about XSLT itself. So I regret I can't help you with it.

Comment: @_trivial: It isn't a good practice to view the transformation result in the browser. Use any good text editor or one of the XSLT IDEs out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Pushing all the old complaints down).

It turns out I can get this to work by using select attributes. So it's broken for text node values (at least it seems). So here is what I did. I modified your XML to do this:

```
  ...
  <xsl:param name="evalue" select="cccc"/>  
  <xsl:param name="ename"  select="c"/>
  ...
```

And then realizing that I was getting a document *fragment* ( `XML::DOM::DocumentFragment` ) as $xslt->result_document, I used the document owner, and changed the print line to:

print "\n---\n", $xslt->result_document->getOwnerDocument->toString, "\n---\n";

However, it looks like the old document. And I'd really suggest using something else, it has open and new bugs from 2005-2006: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=XML-XSLT And the last resolved bug was also 6 years ago: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Status=Resolved&Name=XML-XSLT

The more I crawl around in the code, the more things I see wrong with it.

---

What do you mean "it doesn't work"?!! Are you getting a stack trace, like I am? From what I can see, (in version 0.48 that I have), this module is abandonware and probably for good reason.

- The only way it stores an XML document is `open_xml` which is called only in `open_project` or `transform`.
- `open_project` is not called internally, and `transform` is only called by `serve` which is not called internally

However,

- `new` always calls `open_xsl`
- Which always calls `__preprocess_stylesheet`
- Which always calls `__extract_top_level_variables`
- Which attempts to parse the variable and param elements and if that element doesn't have a `select` attribute (which you don't have) it tries to call `xml_document` and then its `createDocumentFragment` method. However, it hasn't (as far as I can see) allowed you to set the `xml_document`. It probably meant to call `xsl_document`. But by the time it gets here, it's already stored an `XML::DOM::Element` *NOT* the Document as a mandatory part of `__get_stylesheet` called all the time from `__preprocess_stylesheet` before `__extract_top_level_variables` was called.

So when I left the call as `xml_document` it told me:
 `Can't call method "createDocumentFragment" on an undefined value`. But if you assign that to the more correct `xsl_document` field you get told 
`Can't locate object method "createDocumentFragment" via package "XML::DOM::Element"`.

I believe that [`XML::LibXSLT`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aLibXSLT) is much more standard, anyway.

Comment: i got the following error:XML::LibXSLT object version 1.70 does not match bootstrap parameter 1.75 at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 223. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/XML/LibXSLT.pm line 44.